# With Sharepoint hosted Excel file I'm getting the error message "trouble signing in" when trying "Open in Desktop App"

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, user-accounts, excel-online

I'm unable to Open any Excel files on my Desktop Excel App from Sharepoint "Open in App" or Excel online "Open in Desktop App".

I'm able to log into my company's Sharepoint, and Office365 with my business credentials using my company login, which for the sake of argument I'll call **Frank@mycompany.com**.  I have an old personal hotmail account that I use on my desktop, Frank****@hotmail.com.  And I have Excel Professional 2010 Desktop installed.

When I try to open an excel file from Sharepoint on my desktop with "Open in App" or "Open in Desktop App", I get the sign in error as pictured below. Where even though signed in as **Frank@mycompany.com** Excel is stating that User acccount **Frank****@hotmail.com** does not exist in tenant 'Mycompany'.

I'm using a newly installed Edge browser that doesn't have me signed in on anything with my personal email, **Frank****@hotmail.com**, so where is Excell getting **Frank****@hotmail.com**, and why does it think I should be singing in with that, instead of opening it and singing in with my company credentials, **Frank@mycompany.com**?

Excel does explicately ask for a sign in, it just does this automatically.  Also, I can download the Excel file from Sharepoint or Excel online and open it with my desktop Excel with no problems.

Anyways, I appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn’t reproduce your issue. Please try as following:

Open Excel Professional 2010 Desktop, click **File** and choose **Open**, then input library URL(`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/Document Library`) to open an document and check the result.

If the issue still exists, open Edge in **InPrivate** window and re-open the document  in desktop to test.

[image]

Comment: When I try the from Excel, or in Edge private mode I'm getting the same message, that "User acccount Frank**@hotmail.com** from 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Mycompany'.  I guess I'll upgrade, but I'd like to know, where is Excel getting my Frank**@hotmail.com** from 'live.com' from.  I'm not signed into anything.  Is it becasue my Excel is regester to that email address?  Can I change that?

Comment: It's a strange behavior. I am afraid it's hard to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2010 is not supported with SharePoint Online. You'll need to upgrade, first.

https://docs.microsoft.com/deployoffice/endofsupport/office-365-services-connectivity

In addition, Office must be signed in as the same user that has access to SPO.

Comment: OK, I'm going to upgrade, but not sure if that's totally going to fix the issues since it will be on my personal laptop......  but since I'm getting the error, "User acccount Frank**@hotmail.com** from 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Mycompany' it seeems like a permissions issue??  Do you know where Excel would be getting my Frank**@hotmail.com** from 'live.com' credentials if I'm not logged into anything?  Should it be asking for a log in?